# Pass an id on clicking a div to the modal and display data based on the id inside the modal

Tags: php

This is my MySQL code in which a div is generated automatically:

```
<?php
    $sql = "select id,city, event_date, capacity, eb_deadline, regular_deadline, venue, earlybirdstudentprice, regularstudentprice, lastminutestudentprice, earlybirdstudentcount, regularstudentcount, lastminutestudentcount, earlybirdproprice, regularproprice, lastminuteproprice, earlybirdprocount, regularprocount, lastminuteprocount from tbl_events";

    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

        $id = $row['id'];
        $city = $row['city'];
        $event_date = $row['event_date'];

        $date = date('F d', strtotime($event_date));

        $capacity = $row['capacity'];
        $eb_deadline = $row['eb_deadline'];
        $regular_deadline = $row['regular_deadline'];
        $venue = $row['venue'];
        $earlybirdstudentprice = $row['earlybirdstudentprice'];
        $regularstudentprice = $row['regularstudentprice'];
        $lastminutestudentprice = $row['lastminutestudentprice'];
        $earlybirdstudentcount = $row['earlybirdstudentcount'];
        $regularstudentcount = $row['regularstudentcount'];
        $lastminutestudentcount = $row['lastminutestudentcount'];
        $earlybirdproprice = $row['earlybirdproprice'];
        $regularproprice = $row['regularproprice'];
        $lastminuteproprice = $row['lastminuteproprice'];
        $earlybirdprocount = $row['earlybirdprocount'];
        $regularprocount = $row['regularprocount'];
        $lastminuteprocount = $row['lastminuteprocount'];
?>

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
        <a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">
        <img src="img/bang.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%"></a>
        <h4><b><?php echo $date; ?>, <?php echo $city; ?></b></h4>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

Now upon clicking on the div, I want to pass the id of the data displayed in that div to the modal and fetch data based on it to display it inside the modal. My modal code is:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" align="center">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content" align="center">
      <div class="modal-header" align="center">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <!-- <h2 class="modal-title">You're buying Tickets for</h2><br> -->
        <h1 class="modal-title"><br>3D Printing Workshop</h1><br>
        <h4 class="modal-title">July 14, Mumbai</h4>
        <h5 class="modal-title">9.30 AM - 4.30 PM</h5><br>
        <h5 class="modal-title">iKeva, Lower Ground 2, Art Guild House, Phoenix Market City, Mumbai 123456</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" align="center">

                <div class="container">
    <div class="tabs">
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
            <div class="title">
                <h2>1. Choose Attendee Type</h2><br>
                <h5><em>Tickets are strictly available on a First Come First Serve Basis only. <br> Students have to provide valid Student ID cards during Check-in</em></h5><br>
            </div>
            <br>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
              <li class="active" ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#professionals">Professionals</a></li>
              <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#students">Students</a></li>
            </ul>
            <br>
            <form>
                <div class="tab-content">
                  <div id="professionals" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Early Bird Ticket</td>
                                <td>Ends on Mar 17</td>
                                <td>5 Left</td>
                                <td><select class="form-control" id="tickets">
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>x</td>
                                <td>Rs. 1499/-</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Regular Ticket</td>
                                <td>Ends on Mar 20</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><select class="form-control" id="tickets1" disabled>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>x</td>
                                <td>Rs. 1999/-</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Last Minute Ticket</td>
                                <td>Ends on Mar 24</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><select class="form-control" id="tickets2" disabled>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>x</td>
                                <td>Rs. 2999/-</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td colspan="4"><hr style="width: 100%; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="text" style="font-size: 12px;" placeholder="Discount Coupon"><button class="btn btn-link">Apply</button></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td colspan="3"><em>(incl of all taxes)</em></td>
                                <td>Rs. 1998/-</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <div id="students" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Early Bird Ticket</td>
                                <td>Ends on Mar 17</td>
                                <td>5 Left</td>
                                <td><select class="form-control" id="tickets3">
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>x</td>
                                <td>Rs. 1499/-</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Regular Ticket</td>
                                <td>Ends on Mar 20</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><select class="form-control" id="tickets4" disabled>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>x</td>
                                <td>Rs. 1999/-</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Last Minute Ticket</td>
                                <td>Ends on Mar 24</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><select class="form-control" id="tickets5" disabled>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>x</td>
                                <td>Rs. 2999/-</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td colspan="4"><hr style="width: 100%; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="text" style="font-size: 12px; text-align: center;" placeholder="Discount Coupon"><button class="btn btn-link">Apply</button></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td colspan="3"><em>(incl of all taxes)</em></td>
                                <td>Rs. 1998/-</td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>

                    <div class="title">
                        <h2>2. Attendee Details</h2><br>
                        <h5><em>Please enter details of individual Attendee(s). <br> In case of multiple attendees, Billing details should be same as the first Attendee.</em></h5><br>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <table class="table" id="attendees">

                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Name"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Email"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Mobile No."></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>

                    </table>

            </form>
        </div>  
    </div>

</div>



        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for ur answer. I guess you didn't understand my ques. This is not  what I want.

Comment: I think your questions could look *much* better with only a little [improvement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163).

Answer (score 0):

Wihout the need for all of your code, you can do this quite easily.

```
<div>
  <div id="hello" style="background-color:red; color :white;text-align:center; padding: 10px;">
  <span id="this">blah blah</span>
  <span id="something">More info</span>
  </div>
</div>
  <hr>
  <div id="modal">
    <div id="here1">Nothing</div>
    <div id="here2">Nohing2</div>
  </div>
```

And use this jQuery to grab the values and populate your modal:

```
$('div#hello').click(function(){
  var first= $('#this').html();
  var second= $('#something').html();
  $('#here1').html(first);
  $('#here2').html(second);
});
```

See i in action here: http://jsbin.com/rulaqabane/edit?html,js,output

Fetching your data after that is a separate issue!

Update:

```
$('div#hello').click(function(){
      var id= $('#id').html();
      $.get('/my/api/resource', {id: id}, function(data){
            $('#target').html(data.whatever);
      });
    });
```

Comment: I want to do it using data only. I want to pass the id to the modal when cicking on a div

Comment: well, grab a var which is the id then, and make your ajax call. if your api returns json, use that data to populate with .html()

Comment: Can u give show an example code. I want to retrieve another set of data using the id which I am passing. Here the id is the database row id